# Store and use compass and dip with QField

Tags: mapping, qfield, geology

We will be using QField for structural measurement and geological mapping. Tablet and cell phone can measure plane orientation and dip. How can we set-up these measurement with QField?

Comment: What do you mean by "set up this measurement"?

Comment: Hi, sorry for confusion. It mean to create a field in QField. When you stop at a station, you take a direction of a structural plan, where the Tablet give you the orientation as well as the dip. You could "lock" these values in a field.

Comment: See video around 1:20 and 1:40. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3a6AvbVWgQ

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an option yet, you have to manually measure and enter the azimuth/dip. It could be supported as a future QField feature, there is interest in the geoscience community but needs leadership / money.

Comment: Well thank you! I will get my good old Brunton out again!

Comment: See feature request for QField: https://github.com/opengisch/QField/issues/1882